# background-image stretch to fit beyond viewport

Tags: css, background-image, background-size

I have a page where I want a full-screen background image. This works fine when the the body fits within the viewport, I have html { height: 100%; } and body { min-height: 100%; padding-top: 70px; ... background-size: cover; } (the top padding is for a page header). The issue arises when the page becomes larger than the viewport. The body stretches to the correct height, however the background attachment never grows larger than the size of the viewport. Here is a sample fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/xdsgek6t/]. In the live version there is also an image overlay, but in the fiddle you can easily see the line where the radial gradient ends, even though I've told it to cover the body, which in this fiddle is 3000px tall due to a child element.

```css
html { height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background-color: #363636;
  min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #1976D2;
 background-image: radial-gradient( circle at top right, #64B5F6 0%, #1976D2 90% );
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 background-position: right 70px;
 background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.something { height: 3000px; width: 10px; }
header { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; height: 70px; z-index: 500; background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="something"></div>
</body>
```

This ends up looking really strange when the page grows a tiny bit larger, and is really evident on mobile.

Comment: add a background color to html, and body background will effectively be drawn on body background. it is a funny thing here about bg on HTML/BODY . when you set a background on either one of them, it is drawn on HTML. So to make the difference , set a rule for both of them and do not use transparent as a bg-color but any plain color will be fine  ... https://jsfiddle.net/xdsgek6t/2/

Comment: some reference to add to my previous comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#root-background

Comment: very interesting, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%;` from `html` and it will extend. And if you need `min-height: 100%` on `body`, you can use `min-height: 100vh` instead, and that will not rely on `height: 100%` on `html`

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background-color: #363636;
  min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: #1976D2;
 background-image: radial-gradient( circle at top right, #64B5F6 0%, #1976D2 90% );
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 background-position: right 70px;
 background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.something { height: 3000px; width: 10px; }
header { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; height: 70px; z-index: 500; background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="something"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. And that is exactly why I had html 100%, so thanks for the 100vh suggestion.

Comment: @AdamMarr sweet, np.